# How do i include php variable in jquery using cake php

Tags: jquery

I was working for making multilanguage site in cake php, How do i include php variable inside jquery in cake php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge them directly...because when javascript is executed by any browser...the php code is already executed...all you can do is set a value from php variable to js by echo..

This is a small example:

```
<?php
    $a = 2;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var value =<?php echo $a;  ?>;
    // it prints var value =2; in your browser ...so...
    //  do some stuff with value in js....
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Morgado,  Thanks for the reply here is my code and where i implement as u r sugession but it keep on loading cannot see anything..please find the code below

Comment: <?php    
   $err1 = __("fund detail error");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFunds_p(){  
  jQuery('#fund_error_p').html("");
  var amount = parseInt(jQuery("#fund_amount_p").val());
   var merr=<? echo $err1;  ?>;    
   if(jQuery("#fund_amount_p").val().length<=0){
    jQuery('#fund_error_p').show();
    jQuery('#fund_error_p').html("<font color='red'><b>"+merr+"</b></font>");
  }else{
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
</script>

Comment: yep...I think you need to use <?php echo $err1; ?> and not <? echo $err1; ?>

Comment: Hi morgado, thanks for the reply.. i have used like what u had said but still same ..any idea..

Comment: ok...so...what's the html output you have in the browser for this that code?

Comment: It just loads ..with out any out put ..:( iam using modal popup where the code is implemented.Thanks for the support..

Comment: Hi Morgado i have placed u r example in sample file and tested that is working so i need to find how to place correctly in my script ...:)..thanks any ways ..can u give me suggesions for jquery ...

Comment: var contramt='<?php echo $contramount;?>';  with in quotes then it started working ..thanks for your support :)

Comment: you say inside another js file that isn't the same of php output?...I think the only one way is by declare a global js variable in a the original html/php document and after that, you could use that variable in  whatever external js file :)

Comment: Hi Morgado i have included seperate js for each language..:) easy way